# How to find element when it's in <P tag in html file using webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to find element in `<p>` tag from html file. This part of html displays a warning message in a webpage.

The html code is here:

```
<div class="Coeff-Details">
    <div>
        <p class="alert alert-warning">There is no data to display</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I cannot find the element after class, I tried this without success.

```
driver.findElement(By.name("alert alert-warning">There is no data to display")).isDisplayed();
```

I tried the same thing but with xpath, it did not find the element.

Do you know how to find this element?
Thank you

Comment: @shri046 probably not the best link to give - it is about locating elements in selenium-ide while the OP is using java webdriver bindings.

Comment: @alecxe You are right, oversight on my part. Could not edit my own comment so re-posting it with WebDriver reference.

Please make sure you have gone through [WebDriver documentation](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted) that covers some of the basics around using the WebDriver API. The selector you have used is incorrect and will not work in fetching the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to find the element, here are some of them:

- by *class name*

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("alert-warning"));
  ```
- by *xpath*

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//div[@class="Coeff-Details"]/div/p[@class="alert-warning"]'));
  ```
- by *css selector*

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('div.Coeff-Details p.alert.alert-warning'));
  ```

Then, you can get the text using `getText()` method:

```
element.getText();
```

Comment: this is working too assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.cssSelector("p.alert.alert-warning")));

Comment: @kirkdouglas included that option too. Thanks.

Comment: Now i'm not sure because i tried the above assertTrue function in a web page where there is no alert message, the test says There is an Alert message, it's confusing now for me

Comment: @kirkdouglas have u used the selector I've put in the answer? (note - there is `div.Coeff-Details` at the beginning)